# How to get multiple row result on Oracle Report Builder using PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, output, reportbuilder

I want to return the same result which i am getting on sql developer in report builder, whenever i am using the same query in the report builder its returning only one row or result using PL/SQL. Please help me on this.

I have table like below: Need to get the 'name' column result on report builder one by one or print across.

```
select * from emp;

 SL    NAME         CITY        PHONE     JOB    
---- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------------
 1    PRADEEP     MANGALORE   66455466    MANAGER         
 2    PRASHANTH   UDUPI       553453      PRESIDENT       
 3    NELSON      MOODABIDRE  255343      A MANAGER       
 4    JACKSON     KAUP        234534663   CLERK           
 5    JOHN        MANGALORE   9947848     CLERK           
 6    DEXIE       MANGALORE   122324324   CLERK           
 7    SUKESH      KAUP        44266373    LINE MANAGER    
 8    YASER       TAMILNADU   4423424     PRESIDENT       
 9    MITHUN      KASARAGOD   3234242     CLERK           
 10   ABU         AJMAN       54636673    SUPERVISOR   

10 rows selected
```

Now I have a pl/sql query to return name only. This is without loop.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
  CURSOR C1 IS SELECT NAME FROM EMP WHERE JOB = 'CLERK';
  JOBS VARCHAR2(2000);
  RES VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN 
  OPEN C1;
  FETCH C1 INTO JOBS;
  CLOSE C1;

  RES := JOBS;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RES);
END;
```

this code returns:

```
anonymous block completed

JACKSON
```

If I apply this on the report builder using return (DOPL will not work on Oracle Report Builder so using RETURN) this block will give me the same result as above.

Will try with loop (This step is very important for me)

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
  CURSOR C1 IS SELECT NAME FROM EMP WHERE JOB = 'CLERK';
  JOBS VARCHAR2(2000);
  RES VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN 
  OPEN C1;

  LOOP
    FETCH C1 INTO JOBS;
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

    res := jobs;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(res);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE C1;
END;
```

In SQL Developer this will return below:

```
anonymous block completed

JACKSON
JOHN
DEXIE
MITHUN
```

Same I tried in Oracle Report Builder using return instead of `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`, but it is returning as below:

```
anonymous block completed

JACKSON
```

second block while executed on sql developer giving me all the record where job = clerk but in report builder it is not giving me correct result. In Report Builder it should give 4 rows but its returning only one row. So i need to know how to get this 4 rows on Report Builder.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: so you are saying the first cursor block is returning wrong data ?

Comment: No sathya first cursor is also returning the correct one. There i have not used loop so its returning first row. Now i am concerned about second block.

Comment: No sathya first cursor is also returning the correct one. There i have not used loop so its returning first row. Now i am concerned about second block while executed on sql developer giving me all the record where job = clerk but in report builder it is not giving me correct result. In Report Builder it should give 4 rows but its returning only one row. So i need to know how to get this 4 rows on Report Builder.

Comment: Will i get the proper result if i use while loop??

Comment: I am testing your scenario localy and ill tell you what i get

Comment: in pslql your code look fine I dont have oracle report to test it

Comment: The RETURN statement in a function exits the function with a value.  So the first time your code encounters the RETURN statement if figures it's done.

Comment: So what best can be done Sentinel?? Any idea??

Comment: What is your report actually based on? A function, an anonymous block, or a simple query (like `SELECT NAME FROM EMP WHERE JOB = 'CLERK'`)? As Sentinel says, you can't just put a `RETURN` in the middle of a loop, it will exit the loop prematurely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this after I modified the code as below:

```
 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

        DECLARE
          CURSOR C1 IS SELECT NAME FROM EMP WHERE JOB = 'CLERK';
          JOBS VARCHAR2(2000);
          RES VARCHAR2(2000);

      n1 number default null;
    BEGIN 
      OPEN C1;

      LOOP
      if n1 is null  then 
        FETCH C1 INTO JOBS;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        res := jobs||chr(10);
         else 
      res:= res||chr(10)||jobs;
    end if;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(res);
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE C1;
    END;
```